# 3D coordinates as the output of a Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, coordinates, regression, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Neural Networks are mostly used to classify. So, the activation of a neuron in the output layer indicates the class of whatever you are classifying.

Is it possible (and correct) to design a NN to get 3D coordinates? This is, three output neurons with values in ranges, for example [-1000.0, 1000.0], each one.

Comment: Depending on the software package and activation function you use, you probably want to normalize the value range [-1000.0, 1000.0] to be either [0, 1] or [-1, 1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.** You can [use a neural network to perform linear regression](http://briandolhansky.com/blog/artificial-neural-networks-linear-regression-part-1), and more complicated types of regression, where the output layer has multiple nodes that can be interpreted as a 3-D coordinate (or a much higher-dimensional tuple).

To achieve this in TensorFlow, you would create a final layer with three output neurons, each corresponding to a different dimension of your target coordinates, then minimize the [root mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) between the current output and the known value for each example.